# How do I pass properties to Enver in Grails 3?

Tags: hibernate, grails, configuration, hibernate-envers, grails-3.3

I am using Hibernate Envers in my Grails app, and trying to set the `org.hibernate.envers.audit_strategy` property. What is the correct way to configure this?

I have tried adding the following to `application.yml`:

```
org.hibernate:
    envers:
        audit_strategy: 'org.hibernate.envers.strategy.ValidityAuditStrategy'
```

I tried several variations on this, and also tried setting it in `application.groovy`, but I cannot get Envers to read it.

I'd rather include it in the project source, and not set it on the command line.

**Update:**

Another config that does not work (`application.yml`):

```
hibernate:
    additionalProperties:
        org.hibernate:
            envers:
                audit_strategy: 'org.hibernate.envers.strategy.ValidityAuditStrategy'
```

**Update 2:**

I noticed in the debugger that there is a nested map in the config, as shown in the screenshot below. This prevents `AuditEntitiesConfiguration` from reading the property correctly, since it's just using `map.get`.

Why is this happening? Is there something wrong with my YAML format?

[image]

I tried simplifying my YAML setting for this property down to one line, but it didn't help:

```
org.hibernate.envers.audit_strategy: 'org.hibernate.envers.strategy.ValidityAuditStrategy'
```

Answer (score 2):

I found that I could make it work by modifying the `Application` class:

```
    static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty('org.hibernate.envers.audit_strategy', 'org.hibernate.envers.strategy.ValidityAuditStrategy')
        GrailsApp.run(Application, args)
    }
```

I'm open to better solutions.